# In a dogfight, can a pilot shoot down a parachute?

Tags: dogfighting, fighter

Forgive me if my question sounds more like a rule of engagement for aerial combat than aviation technique. I was wondering that is it ok, in a dogfight, for a victorious pilot to shoot a defeated pilot's parachute to kill him. Are there any records of this type of event?

Comment: That would be terrible if someone did shoot the pilot after he was ejected out of the aircraft. The reason this rule is out here is because the pilot can cause no harm if he is not in the jet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You question *is* a question of rules of engagement. Shooting down a downed pilot in a dogfight is not only *not OK*, but also *illegal*.

According to [Article 42 of Geneva Conventions](https://www.icrc.org/applic/ihl/ihl.nsf/Article.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=0E0BF3B27E4F4E8EC12563CD0051DB78),

> No person parachuting from an aircraft in distress shall be made the object of attack during his descent.

Of course, war is war and this kind of attacks [have been practiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attacks_on_parachutists) by pilots of almost all air forces, though it should be noted that in most cases, this practice was specifically prohibited by their high commands.

Comment: That's specifically Article 42 of Additional Protocol 1, which was not part of the original 4 Geneva Conventions and has not been ratified by as many states. However, this specific provision appears to be customary international law as well.

Comment: Yes. Still the Conventions cover most of the international conflicts and I thought it would be appropriate to quote it here.

Comment: Yeah, I was just pointing it out to be more specific.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attacks_on_parachutists) on this subject is actually pretty good.

Comment: There are numerous recorded instances from the Second World War of pilots being killed after bailing out of their aircraft, this was very common particularly in the later war years.